# How can we parameterise Azure Synapse Spark Jobs?

Tags: azure-synapse

The Spark Jobs UI in Azure Synapse has the option to pass command line arguments to the underlying code, but there doesn't appear to be any option to parameterise these arguments.

Similarly the Spark Job Definition activity in Azure Pipelines doesn't offer any parameterisation options.

Is there any way to pass parameters to a Azure Synapse job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there in Azure Synapse Pipelines. Released May 2021.

[image]

Comment: Looks totally different than this.  Also how do we parameterize a .net job?

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, the product team working on the public document/tutorial on How can we parameterise Spark jobs.

For now, you can use the job definition JSON file to parameterize the Spark job. Attached one sample file:

```
{
  "targetBigDataPool": {
    "referenceName": "yifso-1019",
    "type": "SparkComputeReference"
  },
  "requiredSparkVersion": "2.4",
  "jobProperties": {
    "name": "job definition sample",
    "file": "wasbs://ContainerName@StorageName.blob.core.windows.net/SparkSubmission/artifact/default_artifact.jar",
    "className": "sample.LogQuery",
    "args": [],
    "jars": [],
    "pyFiles": [],
    "archives": [],
    "files": [],
    "conf": {
      "spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.StorageName.blob.core.windows.net": "StorageAccessKey"
    },
    "numExecutors": 2,
    "executorCores": 4,
    "executorMemory": "14g",
    "driverCores": 4,
    "driverMemory": "14g"
  }
}
```

The job definition JSON can be modified, imported, and run directly.

Comment: which field in this sample file is the parameter that gets it value passed in from synapse?